# Question about A051002 in OEIS

Tags: generating-functions, oeis

I have a question about sequence https://oeis.org/A051002 in the OEIS database with first elements

```
1, 1, 244, 1, 3126, 244.
```

I searched however for

```
1,-1, 244, -1, 3126, -244
```

a sequence described by a Generating Function in Exercise 1.15 of Apostol's MFDSNT.

My question is about the following reference in the sequence description:

"T. M. Apostol, Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory, Springer-Verlag, 1990, page 25, Exercise 15 **(corrected)**."

What is meant with **(corrected)** in this reference? Is there an error in the exercise, perhaps? I searched for an Errata but there is none, so I don't think so. Besides both GF's in the exercise result in

```
1,-1, 244, -1, 3126, -244.
```

Why the reference to Apostol Exercise 1.15 at all, I wonder.

[image]

Comment: $F(x)$ is the generating function mentioned in the [OEIS A051002](https://oeis.org/A051002) reference and formula, though the sequence itself is unsigned.  $G(x)$ is the generating function of [OEIS A001160](https://oeis.org/A001160)

Comment: Is that an answer to "What is meant with (corrected) in this reference?" ? - I agree about G(x). - I disagree about F(x). How have you calculated the sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [OEIS sequence A051002](https://oeis.org/A051002)
is "Sum of 5th powers of odd divisors of n."
The reference to Apostol with "Exercise 15 (corrected)"
is not clear here, but certainly refers to the fact that the exercise refers to

> and let $$ F(x) = \sum_{n=1\\ n\,\text{odd}}^\infty
> \frac{n^5 x^n}{1+x^n}.$$

whereas the OEIS entry has a formula

> Compare this with the Apostol reference which gives the g.f. of a(n)*(-1)^(n+1). - Wolfdieter Lang, Jan 31 2017

which explains that there is an alternating sign
difference in the two sequences. Thanks to
your question, I have modified the OEIS entry
to remove the "(corrected)".

Comment: This MMa code generates the sequence ( first 21 elms but can be extended of course ) :
Rest[CoefficientList[
 Sum[(Series[n^5 x^n/(1 + x^n) /. n :> a, {x, 0, 21}] // Normal), {a, 
   1, 21, 2}], x]]

Comment: `Rest@CoefficientList[ Series[ Sum[n^5 x^n/(1 + x^n), {n, 1, 21, 2}], {x, 0, 21}] // Normal, x]` is slightly better.

Comment: In the spirit of Apostol:  
g[n_] := DivisorSigma[5, n] /; IntegerQ[n]
g[n_] := 0 /; Not[IntegerQ[n]]
f[n_] := g[n] - 34 g[n/2] + 64 g[n/4]
Table[f[n], {n, 1, 21}]